# kafka-node, How to keep nodejs connection when broker is down?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I just npm install kafka-node and using kafka_0.9.2-0.8.2.1. I have one nodejs and two brokers, kafka1, kafka2. The zookeeper is in kafka1. Following codes in nodejs client:(which is in node_js_machine). When I kill kafka process which nodejs currently connects. The nodejs crushes and exited. The main problem is in error handling, if I comment 4 lines as follows (problem lines), then even I kill borker, the node does not crushes. I am wondering when broker nodejs connected is down, how to catch this event and reconnect to another broker? Is my error handling correct?

```
var csUtil        = require('cs-js-common');
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Producer = kafka.Producer,
    KeyedMessage = kafka.KeyedMessage,
    client = new kafka.Client('kafka1:2181/','AppAnalyzerStorm'),
    producer = new Producer(client),
    km = new KeyedMessage('key', 'message');
var kafkaConnected = false;

producer.on('ready',function(){
    kafkaConnected = true;
    log.info("kafka producer is connected");
     console.log("kafka producer is connected");
});


producer.on('error',function(err){
    log.error("error in producer on error"+err);
    console.log("producer error is invoked");

    kafka = require('kafka-node');                                             ===========problem line 1                                      
    Producer = kafka.Producer;                                                ===========problem line 2 
    client = new kafka.Client('kafka1:2181/','AppAnalyzerStorm');  ======problem line 3
    producer = new Producer(client);                                                          ======problem line 4
});


producer.send(xxxx)
```

Comment: Why is the `producer.send()` outside 'producer.on('ready', function(){})' ?? is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the end,,,

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Through this, the client will not halt if there are any uncaught exceptions.

But still, to connect to some other broker on `error`, the broker ip address used in `kafka.Client (problem line number - 3)` above must be changed.

Comment: I also asked the this question from https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/209, I got good answer.